# Java Thread Pool and run time creation

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have Java application that allows the user to select a number of devices between 5 - 500.
Once selected the user clicks start and the program creates a thread that represents each device.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(jSlider1.getValue());
Upload[] threads = new Upload[jSlider1.getValue()];

for (int i=0; i < jSlider1.getValue(); i++)
{            
    ThreadListComboBox.addItem("Number "+i);                                                    
    threads[i] = new Upload("Squeak"+i, this.OutputDisplay);            
}

for (int c=0; c < threads.length; c++)
{
    pool.submit(threads[c]);
}
```

This works fine in that I can start lots of threads at runtime this way, the problem I have is managing them. One of the user options is to allow (via the GUI from a combobox) to kill specific devices/threads.

Is it possible using the pool to select a single thread and kill it ?
If not what is the best way to achieve this ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to impl your own [pool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#trpool)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible using the pool to select a single thread and kill it?

The things that you are putting in `threads` are not "threads".  They are `Runnable` or `Callable` instances.  So when you say that you want to kill a thread, you *actually* mean that you want to cancel a submitted task.

If you want to cancel a task, then you need to *keep* the `Future` object that the `submit(task)` method returns, and then call [`cancel(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on it.  If you call `cancel(true)` the thread (if any) that is currently running the task will be interrupted.  However, that is only going to work if your task is designed to respond correctly  to interruption.

You can't kill the thread running the task:

- The methods for doing that kind of thing are **deprecated**.  (They are **unsafe**)
- You cannot get hold of the relevant Thread object anyway.

---

> I thought the ExecutorService was for managing tasks not managing threads. In the program I am writing I want to manage each thread individually.

Ah ... I see.  So in fact what you are describing is NOT a thread *pool* at all.  (You really ought to be a lot more careful with your terminology.  These terms mean specific things.  If you use the wrong terms, people can't understand you!)

In that case, yes, you need an array of threads, or more likely an array of some custom "device" class that has an instance field for the device's thread.  Then you arrange that the GUI calls `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread object for the relevant "device".

This depends on your runnable / callable instances respecting the interrupt flag, etc in their run / call methods.

Comment: Hi, Yes I realised now I misunderstood.  The easy way is to simple make an ArrayList of threads. 
private ArrayList<Thread> pool = new ArrayList<Thread>();

Comment: @DevilCode - no easy way.  And besides, you shouldn't.  You are doing it the right way by using an `ExecutorService`.  What you need to do is to keep and use the `Future` objects.

Comment: I thought the ExecutorService was for managing tasks not managing threads. In the program I am writing I want to manage each thread individually.

Answer (score 1):

The naive way could be to restructure the class to look like this

```
...
...       
private volatile boolean running;

public void stop() {
    running = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        //do some amount of work
    }
}
```

Or you could wrap your workhorses(Your Device Threads) in a Future.

```
List<Future<Output>> taskList = new ArrayList<Future<Output>>();
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; ++i) {
    taskList.add(executor.submit(upLoadObject));
}


// Instead of iterating through the above list and adding tasks individually
// you can also invoke add all the Future<Output> in a list and then invoke it
// together using
// executor.invokeAll(listOfCallables);


//User says shoot the nth task
Future<Output> toCancelTask = taskList.get(n);

//Cancel the task and interrupt it while doing so.
toCancelTask.cancel(true);

//You can also show progress by iterating through the taskList
for (Future<Output> task : taskList) {
    if (task.isDone()) {
       //some jingles. ..
    }
}
```

Your `Upload` class may implement `Callable`if you want to return any result from that thread.

Comment: According to the doc thread.stop() is now depreciated =(( the old ways are gone ... sob.  Any chance you could go into the second option in more detail.

Comment: Hey that is your own stop() method. You poll the `running` variable. Why would I have a running instance variable, if I was _ever_ going to use stop() ?

Comment: ArrayList<Thread> pool = new ArrayList<Thread>(); pool.get(int). only gives thread parameters not Upload class ones so i cant get to the get/set public methods of the class to switch runnable from true to false.

Comment: Hey, Hey you are mixing up the **2** solutions. Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: OK I have a GUI that lets the user select a number of devices between 5 - 500. Each device has its own thread, lets say the user selects 50 devices. 50 threads are loaded squirting data back to the GUI. At any point the user can select devices/threads and kill them. What is the best way to implement that.